# TensorFlow: Non-repeatable results

Tags: python, random, tensorflow

## The Problem

I have a Python script that uses TensorFlow to create a multilayer perceptron net (with dropout) in order to do binary classification. Even though I've been careful to set both the Python and TensorFlow seeds, I get non-repeatable results. If I run once and then run again, I get different results. I can even run once, quit Python, restart Python, run again and get different results.

## What I've Tried

I know some people posted questions about getting non-repeatable results in TensorFlow (e.g., ["How to get stable results..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed), ["set_random_seed not working..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096386/tensorflow-set-random-seed-not-working), ["How to get reproducible result in TensorFlow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293895/how-to-get-reproducible-result-in-tensorflow)), and the answers usually turn out to be an incorrect use/understanding of `tf.set_random_seed()`. I've made sure to implement the solutions given but that has not solved my problem.

A common mistake is not realizing that `tf.set_random_seed()` is only a graph-level seed and that running the script multiple times will alter the graph, explaining the non-repeatable results. I used the following statement to print out the entire graph and verified (via diff) that the graph is the same even when the results are different.

```
print [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

I've also used function calls like `tf.reset_default_graph()` and `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` to avoid any changes to the graph even though this is probably overkill.

## The (Relevant) Code

My script is ~360 lines long so here are the relevant lines (with snipped code indicated). Any items that are in ALL_CAPS are constants that are defined in my `Parameters` block below.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from copy import deepcopy
from tqdm import tqdm  # Progress bar

# --------------------------------- Parameters ---------------------------------
(snip)

# --------------------------------- Functions ---------------------------------
(snip)

# ------------------------------ Obtain Train Data -----------------------------
(snip)

# ------------------------------ Obtain Test Data -----------------------------
(snip)

random.seed(12345)
tf.set_random_seed(12345)

(snip)

# ------------------------- Build the TensorFlow Graph -------------------------

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    
    x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, N_INPUT])
    y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, N_CLASSES])
    
    # Store layers weight & bias
    weights = {
        'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_INPUT, N_HIDDEN_1])),
        'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_1, N_HIDDEN_2])),
        'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_2, N_HIDDEN_3])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_3, N_CLASSES]))
    }
    
    biases = {
        'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_1])),
        'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_2])),
        'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_3])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_CLASSES]))
    }

# Construct model
    pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, USE_DROP_LAYERS, DROP_KEEP_PROB)
    
    mean1 = tf.reduce_mean(weights['h1'])
    mean2 = tf.reduce_mean(weights['h2'])
    mean3 = tf.reduce_mean(weights['h3'])

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y_))
    
    regularizers = (tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h1']) + tf.nn.l2_loss(biases['b1']) +
                    tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h2']) + tf.nn.l2_loss(biases['b2']) +
                    tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h3']) + tf.nn.l2_loss(biases['b3']))
    
    cost += COEFF_REGULAR * regularizers
    
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cost)
    
    out_labels = tf.nn.softmax(pred)
    
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    
    tf.get_default_graph().finalize()  # Lock the graph as read-only
    
    #Print the default graph in text form    
    print [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
    
    # --------------------------------- Training ----------------------------------
    
    print "Start Training"
    pbar = tqdm(total = TRAINING_EPOCHS)
    for epoch in range(TRAINING_EPOCHS):
        avg_cost = 0.0
        batch_iter = 0
        
        train_outfile.write(str(epoch))
        
        while batch_iter < BATCH_SIZE:
            train_features = []
            train_labels = []
            batch_segments = random.sample(train_segments, 20)
            for segment in batch_segments:
                train_features.append(segment[0])
                train_labels.append(segment[1])
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels})
            line_out = "," + str(batch_iter) + "\n"
            train_outfile.write(line_out)
            line_out = ",," + str(sess.run(mean1, feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels}))
            line_out += "," + str(sess.run(mean2, feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels}))
            line_out += "," + str(sess.run(mean3, feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels})) + "\n"
            train_outfile.write(line_out)
            avg_cost += sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels})/BATCH_SIZE
            batch_iter += 1
    
        line_out = ",,,,," + str(avg_cost) + "\n"
        train_outfile.write(line_out)
        pbar.update(1)  # Increment the progress bar by one
    
    train_outfile.close()
    print "Completed training"


# ------------------------------ Testing & Output ------------------------------

keep_prob = 1.0  # Do not use dropout when testing

print "now reducing mean"
print(sess.run(mean1, feed_dict={x: test_features, y_: test_labels}))

print "TRUE LABELS"
print(test_labels)
print "PREDICTED LABELS"
pred_labels = sess.run(out_labels, feed_dict={x: test_features})
print(pred_labels)

output_accuracy_results(pred_labels, test_labels)

sess.close()
```

## What's not repeatable

As you can see, I'm outputting results during each epoch to a file and also printing out accuracy numbers at the end. None of these match from run to run, even though I believe I've set the seed(s) correctly. I've used both `random.seed(12345)` and `tf.set_random_seed(12345)`

## Set-up details

TensorFlow version 0.8.0 (CPU only)
Enthought Canopy version 1.7.2  (Python 2.7, not 3.+)
Mac OS X version 10.11.3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set operation level seed in addition to graph-level seed, ie

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
graph_level_seed = 1
operation_level_seed = 1
tf.set_random_seed(graph_level_seed)
b = tf.nn.dropout(a, 0.5, seed=operation_level_seed)
```

Comment: Wow. Do you need to set an operation-level seed for _every_ operation? All the `tf.placeholder`, `tf.Variable`, `tf.reduce_mean`, etc.?

Comment: No, just the ones that have randomness

Comment: @Yaroslav I don't get it: I would assume the purpose of `tf.set_random_seed()` is to affect all random operations in the graph, so you don't have to set manually a seed for each random operator.  What is its use otherwise?  And from the example in the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#set_random_seed) they only set the global seed to get reproducible results.

Comment: From the doc it seems just `tf.set_random_seed()` would make the script deterministic. At one point it wasn't sufficient, so it's possible that there was a bug that required both seeds to be set that has been fixed since

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, does setting a seed in dropout mean that each pass through the graph will yield the same exact sample?

Answer (score 11):

See this tensorflow [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2732).  Some operations on the GPU are not fully deterministic (speed vs precision).

I also observed that for the seed to have any effect, `tf.set_random_seed(...)` must be called *before* the `Session` is created.  And also you should either completely restart the python interpreter every time you run your code, or call `tf.reset_default_graph()` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

#### What I did to get reproducible results training and testing a huge deep network using tensorflow.

- This is tested on, **Ubuntu 16.04**, **tensorflow 1.9.0**, **python 2.7**, on both **GPU** and **CPU**
- Add these lines of code before doing anything in your code (first few lines of the main function)

```py
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

SEED = 1  # use this constant seed everywhere

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(SEED)
random.seed(SEED)  # `python` built-in pseudo-random generator
np.random.seed(SEED)  # numpy pseudo-random generator
tf.set_random_seed(SEED)  # tensorflow pseudo-random generator
```

- Reset default graph before starting a session

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()  # this goes before sess = tf.Session()
```

- Find all the tensorflow functions in your code that accepts **seed** as an argument, put your constant seed in all of them (in my code `SEED` is what is used)

Here is a few of those functions: `tf.nn.dropout`, `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer` , etc.

**Note**: This step might seem unreasonable because we are already using `tf.set_random_seed` to set a seed for tensorflow, but trust me, you need this! See [Yaroslav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38469668/4315914)'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

In TensorFlow 2.0 `tf.set_random_seed(42)` has changed to `tf.random.set_seed(42)`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed

That should be the only seed necessary if just using TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Yaroslav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38469668/7550636)'s answer, you should also set numpy seed in addition to operation and graph level seeds, as some backend operations depend on numpy. This did the trick for me `np.random.seed()` with **Tensorflow  V 1.1.0**

Answer (score 0):

It is 2023 and TensorFlow has an experimental feature for this purpose: [tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_op_determinism)

The following code always generates the same output:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(1)
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
print("my random", tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=1, maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32).numpy())
```