# TF - in model_fn pass global_step to seed

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

In Tensorflow Estimator API (`tf.estimator`) is there a way to use the current session within `model_fn` to evaluate a tensor and pass the value to python? I want to have a seed in dropout dependent on the value of `global_step`, but as the former requires `int` the latter is a `tensor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to access the `session` inside `model_fn` to get the current value of `global_step`.

Even if it was possible, changing the seed for `tf.nn.dropout` at each step would create a new Graph operation at each step with a different seed, which will make the graph grow bigger and bigger. Even without a `tf.estimator`, I don't know how you can implement this?

---

I think what you want is to make sure that you get the same randomness between two runs. Setting a graph-level random seed with [`tf.set_random_seed()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) or just using a normal `seed` in the dropout should create a reproducible sequence of masks. Here is an example with code:

```py
x = tf.ones(10)
y = tf.nn.dropout(x, 0.5, seed=42)

sess1 = tf.Session()
y1 = sess1.run(y)
y2 = sess1.run(y)

sess2 = tf.Session()
y3 = sess2.run(y)
y4 = sess2.run(y)

assert (y1 == y3).all()  # y1 and y3 are the same
assert (y2 == y4).all()  # y2 and y4 are the same
```

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469632/tensorflow-non-repeatable-results) provides more details on how to make the graph randomness reproducible.