# how to 'reset' random sequence in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, random, deterministic

I have a graph with GBs of variables, and a random function (e.g. VAE). I'd like to be able to run a function, and always use the same random sequence (e.g. feed a large number of x, and always get the exact same z and y).

I can achieve this using random seeds, such that I always get the same sequence every time I run the script from scratch (i.e. initialise the session). However I'd like to be able to reset the random sequence without destroying the session, so I can call my function over and over (and get the same sequence). Destroying and reinitialising session isn't really ideal as I have GBs of variables which I lose, and reloading each time is a waste. Setting the random seed again (tf.set_random_seed) doesn't seem to have an affect (I presume the seed from tf.set_random_seed is somehow combined with the op seed and baked into the op when it's created?)

Is there any way around this?

I've read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) and a ton of posts regarding random seeds in tensorflow (e.g. [TensorFlow: Resetting the seed to a constant value does not yield repeating results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491262/tensorflow-resetting-the-seed-to-a-constant-value-does-not-yield-repeating-resu), [Tensorflow `set_random_seed` not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096386/tensorflow-set-random-seed-not-working), [TensorFlow: Non-repeatable results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469632/tensorflow-non-repeatable-results), [how to get reproducible result in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293895/how-to-get-reproducible-result-in-tensorflow), [How to get stable results with TensorFlow, setting random seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed)) however I can't get the behaviour I'm after.

E.g. toy code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(0)
a = tf.random_uniform([1], seed=1)

def foo(s, a, msg):
    with s.as_default(): print msg, a.eval(), a.eval(), a.eval(), a.eval()


s = tf.Session()
foo(s, a, 'run1 (first session):')

# resetting seed does not reset sequence. is there anything else I can do?
tf.set_random_seed(0)
foo(s, a, 'run2 (same session) :')

# reinitialising session works, but how to do this without closing session and reinitializing?
# and losing GBs of variables which I'd rather not reload
s.close()
s = tf.Session()
foo(s, a, 'run3 (new session)  :')
```

gives results:

```
run1 (first session): [ 0.53973019] [ 0.54001355] [ 0.43089259] [ 0.30245078]
run2 (same session) : [ 0.112077] [ 0.99792898] [ 0.17628896] [ 0.13141966]
run3 (new session)  : [ 0.53973019] [ 0.54001355] [ 0.43089259] [ 0.30245078]
```

Comment: Python random module has `getstate` and `setstate` methods.   I cannot check it, you can save state, and then reset it. Use random module directly as I can see TF uses it.